# How would I add "Brand" to the layered navigation without having to add the attribute to the product

Tags: layered-navigation

I want to add Brand as one of the filters, however when I do this - it also comes up as an option on the actual product. Is there a way to add the Brand information to each product and have it show up in the layered navigation without having it show up as a drop down on the product?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for. You want to have the attribute brand be filterable but not able to edit it in the backend in a dropdown with products?

Comment: What @sander said.  Are you taking about the drop down on the backend?  Or you're seeing a drop down on your frontend product page?

Answer (score 0):

You can set options for attributes in the Magento admin.

Like using it for layered navigation.
Also can check/uncheck if you want to show it on the productpage.

So go to Catalog / Attributes / Manage Attributes, open the attribute brand and try changing a few options.

Comment: I don't think that's the info he's after.  Question isn't clear.

Comment: Could give it a try...